# Show error in boot menu and not load the gui

Tags: boot, dual-boot

When I restart my msi laptop. It boots into emergency mode and the GUI doesn't start. Instead, it shows a command line as shown in the photo. I haven't done anything that have led to this state. Whenever I turn on the machine this is what is diplayed.

[image: photo of screen with You are in emergency mode...]

Comment: Have u tried typing exit to switch to default mode(since you are in emergency mode)?